# Why doesn't middleware execute after mapping controllers?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware

I am building the most basic of an ASP.NET Core Web API, and after a lot of experimenting on my own, I found that running any middleware (custom, app.run, app.use) after the `.MapControllers()` method doesn't work at all.

```
internal class Startup
{
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoint =>
            {
                endpoint.MapControllers(); 
            });
        }
}
```

I'm asking here because the documentation didn't clarify: how does the `MapControllers()` method affect other middleware in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

> I found that running any middleware (custom, app.run, app.use) after
> the .MapControllers() method doesn't work at all.

The issue might relate the middleware order, using the MapController method, it already find the endpoint and return the response, so it will not invoke the next middleware.

You can refer the following code: in this sample, by using the MapControllser method, it can't match the `/map1`, so we can access it using `https://localhost:44379/map1` (change the port to yours).

[image]

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information, see [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: so in this context /map1 is not mapped to any controller route? I think this wouldn't work if the HandleMapTest1 function was declared as a lambda, no? i don't understand

Comment: `so in this context /map1 is not mapped to any controller route? ` Yes.  `I think this wouldn't work if the HandleMapTest1 function was declared as a lambda, no? `, You can refer to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmClB.png). Or you can create a simple sample to reproduce the problem.